# How can i return a generic List<T> from a generic method<T>()

Tags: c#, generics

Good morning,

I have a class Product{} that has a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<IPropertyItem>> extensions;
```

I save my data with this method:

```
public void SaveItem<T>(T item)
    {
        Type currentType = typeof(T);

        if (!extensions.ContainsKey(currentType))
        {
            extensions.Add(currentType, new List<IPropertyItem>());
        }

        if (currentType == typeof(Discount))
        {
            Discount newDiscount = (Discount)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(Discount));                
            extensions[currentType].Add(newDiscount);
        }
        else if(currentType == typeof(Tax))
        {
            Tax newTax = (Tax)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(Tax));
            extensions[currentType].Add(newTax);
        }
        else if(currentType == typeof(Size))
        {
            Size newSize = (Size)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(Size));
            extensions[currentType].Add(newSize);
        }           
    }
```

now i want to get a list of a certain value type stored in my Dictionary, i mean i want that the method returns me a List like this function:

```
public List<T> GetExtensionsDictionary<T>()
    {
        Type currentType = typeof(T);
        List<T> returnedList = new List<T>();

        if (!extensions.ContainsKey(currentType))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return extensions[T];            
    }
```

The method that is calling above is:

```
List<Discount> myDiscounts = myProduct.GetExtensionsDictionary<Discount>();
```

thnks,

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want an extension method for GetExtensionsDictionary?

Comment: I think the problem is that his `GetExtensionsDictionary` method doesn't compile and he doesn't know how to turn the collections in his dictionary into `List<T>`, thats what I addressed in my answer anyway

Comment: You should introduce type param constraint in order to circumvent unnecessary `Convert.ChangeType` conversion e.g. `public void SaveItem<T>(T item) where T : IPropertyItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is all you want:

```
public List<T> GetExtensionsDictionary<T>()
{
    Type currentType = typeof(T);
    List<T> returnedList = new List<T>();

    if (!extensions.ContainsKey(currentType))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return extensions[currentType].Cast<T>().ToList();            
}
```

You have to index into `extensions` with `currentType` not `T` because `T` is a generic parameter and you need the runtime type that you get with `typeof`.

You can use the linq methods `Cast` and `ToList` to turn the collection at `currentType` in the dictionary into a `List<T>`.  This is making a copy of the list, so be mindful of performance considerations.

Make sure you are `using System.Linq;`

Comment: thnks soo much that was the answer, in fact i tried with that return before but i didnt add the library Linq!!! that was the real problem... again many thanks

Comment: @writer no problemo, please mark it as correct homie Im tryna get those POINTS